# oracle sql developer(4.0.0.12) returns wrong date

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having

It seems that a query of mine returns wrong results, and I'm not sure why. I don't yet rule out the possibility that the SQL is actually doing something else then what I expect/want it to do since I haven't used SQL for a time now.

I post it here because I'm kind a stuck with the why it returns wrong results sometimes.

The error is in the MIN(FIRM.account_recharge.X__INSDATE) (or at least the ones I noticed)

```
SELECT
 FIRM.customer.CUSTOMER_ID,
 FIRM.customer.CORPORATION,
 FIRM.customer.CUSTOMER_NAME_PREFIX,
 FIRM.customer.CUSTOMER_NAME,
 FIRM.account.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
 FIRM.account.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
 FIRM.customer.LANGUAGE,
 FIRM.customer.VALIDATED,
 FIRM.account.X__INSDATE,
 SUM(FIRM.account_recharge.GROSS_VALUE) SUM_FELTOLTESEK,
 MIN(FIRM.account_recharge.X__INSDATE),                                           
 INNER JOIN FIRM.account
 ON FIRM.customer.CUSTOMER_ID = FIRM.account.CUSTOMER
 INNER JOIN FIRM.customer_address
 ON FIRM.account.CUSTOMER = FIRM.customer_address.CUSTOMER          
 INNER JOIN FIRM.account_recharge
 ON FIRM.account.ACCOUNT_ID = FIRM.account_recharge.ACCOUNT         
 GROUP BY FIRM.customer.CUSTOMER_ID,
 FIRM.account.X_INSDATE,
 FIRM.customer.CORPORATION,
 etc,etc
 HAVING MIN(FIRM.account_recharge.X__INSDATE) BETWEEN to_date('2014-JAN. -01','YYYY-MON-DD') AND to_date('2014-DEC. -31', 'YYYY-MON-DD');
```

This code should return information abut our customers, their sum account 'recharging'/'replenishing'/'paying in' , sorry not sure of what word to use here. and their first payment/money upload to their account in 2014. Yet sometimes the return values seems to just ignore the actual first time our client paid in money, and shows the second or third date. (my random manual check returned that around 1/10 of the time the returned values are wrong.)

A costumer of ours can have more the one account linked to him. I'm using Oracle SQL developer (4.0.0.12) please ask if you would like to know anything else about this pickle im in.

Otherwise It seems to work nicely, but if you have any other tuning tip, I would be glad to hear them.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are comparing a date with a malformed string literal. See my answer.

Comment: What is your NLS_DATE_FORMAT? You're doing implicit conversions, which are always bad, and assuming that is set to YY-MON-DD, which is an unusual pattern; it may be interpreting the day and year the wrong way round to what you expect. But I'm not sure if that explains what you describe - that it ignores the actual first time. That would make your window too wide, not too narrow, I think? Can you show some data and actual/expected results? I'm assuming X_INSDATE is actually a DATE type.

Comment: NLS_DATE_FORMAT is the Tools/preferences/database/NLS right? (sorry I wouldn't say that I'm profficent in SQL yet) If thats the one you ask its: RR-MON-DD which is kinda funny, since I recall that I changed it to YYYY-MON-DD (2014.02.21 this is how we write dates in my country). On the return values: It should be like: customer_id, corporation (1 or 0) customer_prefix (usually NULL), customer name, acc type language, validated account, date of the account creation, SUM amount of paid in money, first payment of 2014.

Comment: It seems, my code isn't full, and the name and the tags are wrong as well, I try to change them, to reflect the question here... (sorry about that 2. time posting here)

Comment: @Alex Poole Yes the X_INSDATE is a DATE type (checked it, you were right to ask for I haven't actually checked that! )

Comment: I tried to change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT to YYYY-MON-DD, didn't change the results

Comment: If you have been using different implicit models, you may have messed up data perhaps; can you look at your raw data and check it's all in the century you expect, for example? Really, don't rely on implicit conversions and NLS settings.

Comment: Can I mess up data if I don't commit? I haven't used anything like insert, I doubt that I changed anything in the database,but with my experience this may not mean much. They are all in the good century, and the raw data seems to be okey (there isn't anything from last century)

Comment: Update: I found that it gave dates to accounts that are empty otherwise (money has never been uploaded) I dont really understand, how could this be? (the first I found gave it 2014.01.03 as the date, searching for more examples)

Answer (score 3):

> HAVING MIN(FIRM.account_recharge.X_INSDATE) BETWEEN '14-JAN.  -01' AND '14-DEC.  -31'

This is definitely incorrect. You are comparing dates. so, you must convert the string literal explicitly into a date using **TO_DATE** and proper **format mask**.

For example,

```
HAVING MIN(FIRM.account_recharge.X_INSDATE) 
   BETWEEN to_date('2014-JAN-01','YYYY-MON-DD') 
   AND     to_date('2014-DEC-31', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
```

Also, do not use **YY** to denote the year. You don't have to re-invent the **Y2K** bug again. Always use **YYYY** format for an year. Else, if you are stuck with YY values for year, then use RR format. But, I would insist, always use YYYY format for year.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented the change you suggested, it should be better, still it returns wrong values ('2014-JAN. -01' is the format others gave wrong date format, and I didn't want to change preferences).

Comment: @BasicHumanBeing: Can you please update your initial post, so we can see how you fixed the date conversion. Maybe it is still faulty.

Comment: I'm trying that right now, but I get "An error occured submitting the change" while I try to submit. Edit: I still get the error message, but if I just go back insted of canceling the changes it seems like it has been updated to me. I'm not sure